# Definition of the torsion of a curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I am studying the definition of torsion of a curve.
Is: $\tau (s)=-\frac{dB}{ds}\cdot N $

B= Binormal vector

N= Normal vector

In my textbook, to define the torsion first says that  $\frac{dB}{ds}$ is parallel to N, so exists an scalar $\alpha = - \tau$ / $\frac{dB}{ds}=-\tau \cdot N $ (1)

And then $\frac{dB}{ds}\cdot N=-\tau .N\cdot N=-\tau $

I dont understand why its necessary the "-" before $\tau$ in (1)

Comment: Everything you have written is consistent. Some books do not have this negative sign, but most of us use the convention you have here. What precisely is your question?

Comment: @TedShifrin my question is: is there a reason for the "-" before $\frac{dB}{ds}\cdot N$ or is only a convention? Because i read that there are other definitions for torsion so i thought that maybe the "-" is for make it equivallent to other definition

Comment: I already said this. With the most common definition, the negative is there. A right-handed circular helix has constant positive torsion. DoCarmo — for whatever his reason may be — is the only book I know that uses the opposite sign.

Comment: It's to conform with the right-hand rule.